# Can we use limits for all functions?

Tags: calculus, limits

I a m a high school student who has spent a lot of time learning about limits but still do not understand how they work completely.

What I have understood is that sometimes a function does not have a y-value/s for one/(or more?) x-value/s however, since we know the y-values of the x-values close to the x-value with an undefined y-value we can approximate where the y-value for that x-value will be. To express this we use a concept called limits. My question is, can we use limits for functions where there is a y-value for every X-value? If yes,why would we do that? To show the behaviour of the points of a function as they get closer to a certain point?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Almost every property you will learn in mathematics will only actually apply to a certain set of "nice" objects, and the set of "not nice" objects is often infinitely larger. Despite that, it's useful to look at the properties of the nice objects (and sometimes you can also carve out a small section of the not nice objects that are almost nice, and work with those too). Limits and continuous functions are one such example, where most functions aren't continuous but continuity is still a really useful property to study.

Answer (score 3):

Limits are indeed very important even when you know all the values of a function. In particular, you often want to know that the limit of $f(x)$ when $x$ is near $a$ is what is "should be" - the actual value $f(a)$. That's the precise way to say that the function is *continuous*. Loosely speaking, its graph is a curve with no breaks.

That's true of all the functions you encounter in your early studies:  polynomials, rational functions, trigonometric functions and exponentials and logarithms are all continuous wherever they are defined. That's intuitively clear, but must be proved using the definition of limits (and will be later on in your studies).

The function whose value is $1$ when $x \ne 0$ and is $0$ when $x=0$ is defined everywhere and has limits everywhere but the limit at $0$ is $1$, which is not the value at $0$. To draw its graph you have to hop down to the $x$-axis from the line $y=1$ when $x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

There a few simple examples that show limits can be different from their function, or may simply not exist. One is a [step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function) which is constant except at points where it steps. [Dirichlet's dancing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function) takes this to an extreme where the limits aren't well defined anywhere. We can also consider the [topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve) which shows another type of problem you can have when
trying to define limits near $0$.

The class of functions that agree with their limits are called [continuous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function). They're important in analysis and topology and many familiar functions are continuous like polynomials, exponentials, and trigonometric function.